# Windows phone music player with good playlist capabilities

Tags: music, audio, windows-phone

The built-in music player of Windows Phone 8.0 has an option to create a playlist from the now-playing list but it is extremely rigid. It only allows you to create the playlist, without any options of adding songs to it later or reshuffling the order of the songs, it doesn't even allow you to rename the playlist. That is why I  am looking for **recommendations on a WP 8.0 music player with better playlist capabilities.**

**Necessary capabilities I am looking for are:**

- direct creation of playlists by selecting music available on my phone
- (re)ordering of the songs in the playlist
- adding/removing of songs to the playlist
- renaming of the playlist

**Desired but non-necessary capabilities/features**

- costs less than 5 euros
- ad-free
- adjustable switch time between songs

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements; I recommend 2 candidates:

1. [NiQi Music Player](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/niqi-music-player/9nblggh07r80) (Free)

Features:

- Listen to music with the music player interface beautiful, user-friendly.
- Create playlists simply and quickly.
- Add and search song’s lyrics.
- Utility of music: support for music management.
- Easy Search - Customizable interface simple.
- Create live tile for fast access to play music.
  – Allows the player run in the background.
- Optimized application activity for smoother operation.

  2. [Core Music Player](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/core-music-player/9wzdncrcvllr)  ($1.99)
- Supported playback file types mp3, mp4, aac, flac, wav, wma, 3gp, 3g2, amr, m4a, mpr (Supported bitrates of each codecs are depending on your device and OS version)
- File and folder management create, open, delete, rename, copy, move
- Folder navigation favorite folders, expanded sd card folders, go back, go previous, go forward, open containing folder.
- Music library artists, albums, songs, genres, years, new, background sync
- Selecting to play single or multiple files, playlists, history, single or multiple folders, including or excluding entire subfolders
- Reordering playlist and Now Playing shuffle, sort by name, manual reorder, restore original sequence, overriding player sequence mode, duplicate, remove duplication, find in list
- Misc features search, history, sleep timer, pin playlist to start, pin folder to start, playback control tiles, show state and album art on the live tile, local volume control, fast skip control